# Excel 365 dynamic array to named range without VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, dynamic

Is there any way of putting the contents of a spilled dynamic array into a plain old worksheet named range from a formula or is doing it in VBA the only way?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I don't understand this comment.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Can you explain your end goal and why you wish to create this named range, w/o VBA?

Comment: I like the new dynamic array functions in Excel and would like to keep everything on the worksheet rather than involving VBA. I'm not a programmer so please excuse my pidgin description.

Comment: Sure, but why do you need a named range specifically?

Comment: BB I have a worksheet with a number of named ranges running to 25 columns x 90,000 rows. Made up of text, dates, record numbers, and fields used for record (row) markers. I like combing the text by various searches using FILTER and then marking the spill and putting those marks back in one of the named ranges in the row (record number) being marked. Yes, it can be done with a few lines of code in VBA, but if possible I would like to be able to do that in the worksheet.

Comment: BB,  Thinking about it since learning about the XY think, don't think it applies in my case. I think my question stands on its own as asked.  Be cool.

Comment: I still can't tell what you're actually trying to do but it doesn't sound possible.

Comment: BB, not to belabor the point, but try this. A simple worksheet. A named range called dog, D1:D3.  A spilled dynamic array occupying cells B1:B3. Now a lot of processing might have gone on before you got to the dynamic array B1#. So, here we go is there any way to write B1# (or B1:B3) into the named range "dog" or D1:D3 from the worksheet or do you have to resort to VBA?  I was hoping that it could be done with some of the new array functions. Don't know how this got to be so convoluted. You be cool&all now.

Comment: No this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks BB.  I had almost concluded that, but needed to hear it from an expert. Any idea when Textscript will be available for desktop 365? Be cool&all now.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "Community" does this mean edit the original question which would render the 6 comments confusing or upon editing are all the 7 comments deleted or do I post an entirely new question put more simply? I am new to stackoverflow and do not know the ropes yet. Be cool&all.